# How to include a webpage in javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

My codes are

```
var myurl = "http://domain.tld/document.html";
var mydocument = myurl.document;
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
mydiv.write = mydocument;
```

and

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%" id="mydiv"></div>
```

I do not want to use jQuery! My page have to include the page http://domain.tld/document.html in the div with id mydiv and I want know what is wrong?

Comment: Simple way would be to use an iframe. `<iframe src="http://domain.tld/document.html" style="width:100%;height:100%" />`.

Comment: Are you sure you need javascript, an iframe isn't what you need? `<iframe style="height:100%;width:100%" src="http://domain.tld/document.htmlm"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do an ajax call with XMLHttpRequest() there is a pre html5 method and post html5 method. pre HTML5 does not support the onload event for XMLHttpRequest().

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('Get', '/table1.php', true);

     /* html5 */ 
    xhr.onload = function(e) {/* script to process data here: data = xhr.response  */ 
          mydiv.innerHTML = xhr.response; 
    }
xhr.send();
```

Because of differences jquery ajax is much easier.

Pre HTML5 tutorial on XMLHttpRequest http://www.cristiandarie.ro/asp-ajax/Async.html

You can not use AJAX to process an HTML page from a different domain.

Comment: I use now:
`var myurl = "http://domain.tld/document.html";
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('Get', myurl, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {/* script to process data here: data = xhr.response  */ 
          mydiv.innerHTML = xhr.response; 
    }
xhr.send();`
but I get the error **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.tld/document.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: If domain.tld is under your control, add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mysite1.com'); to the top of table1.php. Replace mysite1.com with the domain where the webpage that is making the request is. Ajax can NOT be done to the local file system. So if you are testing it on your local machine you would get a not allowed. Ajax requests can only be done cross domain using the new standards for data security. If Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not present you will get a not allowed for cross domain.

Comment: And,  If the data is on your site, use ('Get', '/table1.php', true) without the domain.tld, which is one of the changes I made to your original code.